# How are the two states factored out of Deutsch's circuit?

Tags: deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

After placing the Hadamards on the 2 qubits (both initialized in the $|1\rangle$ state) in the circuit, we are given:

$  |\psi_{b}\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|0_{1}0_{2}\rangle -|1_{1}0_{2}\rangle -|0_{1}1_{2}\rangle +|1_{1}1_{2}\rangle) $

the above state is run through the `f-cnot`, and we are given a superposition:

$  |\psi_{c}\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|0_{1}f(0_{2})\rangle -|1_{1}f(1_{2})\rangle -|0_{1}\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle +|1_{1}\tilde f(1_{2})\rangle ) $.

In order to compute whether the function is balanced or not, we can use some factoring:

If $  f(0)=f(1) $ we can factor out:
$   |\psi_{c}\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|0_{1}\rangle -|1_{1}\rangle)(|f (0_{2})\rangle - |\tilde f (0_{2})\rangle)
$

If $  f(0)=\tilde f(1) $ we can factor out:
$   |\psi_{c}\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|0_{1}\rangle +|1_{1}\rangle)(|f (0_{2})\rangle - |\tilde f (0_{2})\rangle)
$

**Question**:

How are these two factored-out states for $ f_1 $ and $ \tilde f_1 $, actually pulled out of the original superposition?  Like, how are they actually factored?

Comment: What do you mean by "actually factored"? Do you need the step-by-step walkthrough for the math, or something different? Have you checked other questions in the "deutsch-jozsa-algorithm" tag, such as https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9838/understanding-steps-in-deutschs-algorithm, that offer that walkthrough?

Comment: haha, yup, i just mean a walkthrough, as you mentioned. I'm having a little trouble following the provided example, could you help to simply walk through the example i provided? I'm sorry, i'm new to this.

Comment: and to quickly add, yes, i definitely have searched answers! thanks again for encouraging me to look back at them

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're having trouble with? I could just paste the walkthrough from my previous answer but if you're finding something specific unclear in it, it will remain unclear :-) Also, you're starting with qubits in |11> before applying the Hadamards, but the typical Deutsch algorithm starts in |01> - could this contribute to your confusion?

Comment: for sure . . . its just the algebra part, ie how from the ψc⟩=1/2(|0f(0)⟩−|1f(1)⟩−|0f~(0)⟩+|1f~(1)⟩) state can we "pull out" (for example, if f(0)=f(1) ) |ψc⟩=1/2(|0⟩−|1⟩)(|f(0)⟩−|f(0)⟩). .. cause there are only half as many terms. is there cancelling out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see how to get from $  |\psi_{c}\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|0_{1}f(0_{2})\rangle -|1_{1}f(1_{2})\rangle -|0_{1}\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle +|1_{1}\tilde f(1_{2})\rangle ) $ to the case of $  f(0)=f(1) $:

$$\frac{1}{2}(|0_{1}f(0_{2})\rangle -|1_{1}f(1_{2})\rangle -|0_{1}\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle +|1_{1}\tilde f(1_{2})\rangle ) = \\ 
= \frac{1}{2}(|0_{1}f(0_{2})\rangle -|1_{1}\color{blue}{f(0_{2})}\rangle -|0_{1}\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle +|1_{1}\color{blue}{\tilde f(0_{2})}\rangle ) = \\
= \frac{1}{2}(|0_{1}\color{blue}{\rangle \otimes |}f(0_{2})\rangle -|1_{1}\color{blue}{\rangle \otimes |}f(0_{2})\rangle -|0_{1}\color{blue}{\rangle \otimes |}\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle +|1_{1}\color{blue}{\rangle \otimes |}\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle ) = \\
= \frac{1}{2}(|0_{1}\rangle \otimes |f(0_{2})\rangle -\color{blue}{|0_{1}\rangle \otimes |\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle-|1_{1}\rangle \otimes |f(0_{2})\rangle} +|1_{1}\rangle \otimes |\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle ) = \\
= \frac{1}{2}\Big(|0_{1}\rangle \otimes \big(|f(0_{2})\rangle - |\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle \big)-|1_{1}\rangle \otimes \big(|f(0_{2})\rangle  -|\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle \big) \Big) = \\
= \frac{1}{2} \big(|0_{1}\rangle - |1_{1}\rangle \big) \otimes \big(|f(0_{2})\rangle - |\tilde f(0_{2})\rangle \big)
$$

And that's exactly the expression in the question. You can see that the number of terms remains the same if you open all brackets, 4.

Comment: Amazing! and thanks for this thoughtful response. In the first step, how are the f(1sub2) just flipped into f(0sub2)? I think this is where im missing some understanding.

Comment: That's because they are equal (f(0) = f(1)). In the other case the not-f(1) will change into f(0)

Comment: thank you! wish i could accept it twice :)

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Comment: also, −|0sub1⟩⊗|f~(0sub2)⟩ get simplified into f~(0sub2)⟩ because 0 state times 0 state = 0 state?

Comment: No, all 2-qbit states remain 2-qubit states, 0 ⊗ 0 remains 00 (it gets distributed into several round brackets, since tensor product behaves similarly to normal product in terms of distributivity), but you can't simplify a 2-qubit state into a 1-qubit state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106315/discussion-between-vp9-and-mariia-mykhailova).